# I am facing issue on setting states of functional hook

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to load a function 5 functions that would do some task and return the response so the hook has has object data type

```js
const [Load, SetLoad] = useState({
    Group : true,
    Workshop : true,
    Event : true,
    Talk: true,
    Project: true
})
```

now I am trying to call the function and update the state  using useEffect hook

```js
useEffect(() => {
AllGroup().then(res => {
    SetLoad({...Load, Group: false})   
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err.response)
})


AllProject().then(res => {
    SetLoad({...Load, Project: false})   
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err.response)
})

AllTalk().then(res => {
    SetLoad({...Load, Talk: false})   
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err.response)
 })

AllEvent().then(res => {
    SetLoad({...Load, Event: false})   
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err.response)
})

AllWorkshop().then(res => {
    SetLoad({...Load, Workshop: false})   
}).catch(err => {
     console.log(err.response)
})
},[]);
```

now the issue I am facing is only one item of the state object is turning to false and rest remains the default value, so can anyone help to fix and update the all the items of the state object

Comment: Looks like there is a more fundamental problem, because of the duplicate code. It would make sense to take a step back, look at those 5 functions code so you can abstract this logic into something more manageable. For example if you were able to have instead an array of 5 items referencing those functions, you could loop them in the useEffect, perhaps with `Promise.all`. You might want to then change your question if you still get stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should to use functional updates. 
E.g.

```
SetLoad(Load=>({...Load, Workshop: false}))
```